# How web browser can shutdown computer

Tags: web-browser

I would like to deverlop one web application, **enduser can configure shutdown computer when task has completed**, i have search via internet but i have nothing to complete that.

Web browser can understand javascript, css and html. i have searched with javascipt([Is it possible to shut down somebody's computer from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528665/is-it-possible-to-shut-down-somebodys-computer-from-a-website)) and the answer is can not.
Silverlight and Flash can not too.

So if browser support that function, does it make some risks ?

Thank for any suggestion !

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227736/how-web-browser-can-shutdown-computer

Comment: I don't understand why i get negative votes(Both Stackoverflow and this site), i just would like to deverlop scheduler webapp.

Comment: This is off topic here. But even if it was on topic it would still get down votes as it is not a well structured question - if you read the [faq] here or the one on SO you will get guidance on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this will be with end user consent, then the easiest would be to write a simple service per each operating system that your clients will use, pack them as convenient installation executables, and host on your web server.

For example on Windows systems, all that service/application would have to do is to start at system boot, listen on some preset port that isn't firewalled, and wait for the server's authentication and shutdown request. Once the request is authenticated in some way that you consider sufficiently secure  (browse tag [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication) for more information), call the [`ExitWindowsEx` Windows API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see link for input parameters documentation).

Of course, users will have to give their consent to run the executable, and depending on a network port used, possibly to disable firewall and enable it to communicate with [WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network) too.

Similar can be achieved for other operating systems as well, if that's even a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I think what your looking for is something like these [HP iLO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out) and [Dell Drac](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/power/en/ps2q02_bell?c=us&l=en)
This way you can not only power off, but you can reboot/turn on/etc computers from a web console (also serial and other protocols).

These are generally speaking, safe. Vulnerabilities crop up from time to time but nothing major recently as far as i'm aware. The obvious risks, if someone gets in is the ability of someone to be able to shutdown your machines at will and potentially cause real hardware damage to your machine.